# Can I get timestamps in a specific format

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetime, timestamp

In VB.Net, I'm using a MySqlDataAdapter to get a table of results from a query to a MySQL database on a server.

Some of the fields in the MySQL database are timestamps.

The data that's getting populated into the table that the MySqlDataAdapter churns out seems to give different end results for these timestamps, depending on the local date display settings of different users.

Is there a way of ensuring that I can get the recorded timestamp from the database in the original MySQL format, even if it's just as a string (eg. "2016-05-20 16:37:00")?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String.Format(obj,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: Thanks. I can iterate through the table that's been received and convert dates this way. I was just hoping that I would be able to adjust a setting in the MySqlDataAdapter itself so that I wouldn't need to then iterate through the results.

Comment: You could make an extension class of it. Then call the extension when you use the value.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll weigh up whether that will be easier overall, or whether it will be more straightforward just to adapt the values after they've been filled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATE_FORMAT(date,format)

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p')  

May 20  2016 06:09  PM
```

You case  "2016-05-20 16:37:00"

```
DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d $h:%i.%s')
```

see this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp for  format pattern

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to format the date within MySQL. I need a way in VB.Net (Visual Studio) of getting a results table from MySQL in which the timestamp fields are in a fixed format that doesn't vary depending on the user's Windows settings.

Comment: I suggest you of select the date in the format proper for your goal.. if you get the data from database in format you need the you don't need other change of format  .. hope is useful

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for explaining. The timestamp field is one of over 40 fields currently being gathered by a "SELECT * FROM..." statement so it will be a bit fiddly to work in the DATE_FORMAT selection but I will give it a go.